# Need to know steps and 'formal process/procedure name' for this Unix/Linux operation

Tags: linux, backup

Right now I'm configuring a version of Ubuntu 18.04 with specific applications, setting configurations, and loading certain files onto it. I'm writing all these steps down in a doc and realized that I do not want to have to go through all this again if my hard drive failed to boot. I did some reading around and I'm not sure exactly what is the name or process of what I'm trying to do but I have an idea (maybe a snapshot mixed with a backup?) but if I want to retain all of these settings, user accounts, the same files, etc... on a separate external hard drive as a fallback what is the approach to doing this? Or if someone guide me to what I'm looking for like I said the terminology is throwing me off :/ Much appreciated :)

Comment: Sounds like you want to look into some sort of imaging software.  If the machine hardware is to be vastly different you might be better off with some sort of configuration management software.

Comment: @Jesse_b it will be the same hardware just a 'backup' just in case something happens to this particular machine I want to be able to quickly plug in a drive and have things somewhat intact

Comment: clonezilla. 4 more to go

Comment: @Jesse_b Did some quick search on imaging software. How about GParted? I have used that to partition my disk before. If I used the Copy/Clone functionality built in to that would that be potentially easier?

Comment: @drewbenn that is only 1 example of what has happened. I actually had something configured and busted some settings that affected some other settings before. Long story short I had to reinstall and follow my guide to get back to that 'stable' OS config that I had before. I guess I'm just trying to treat my OS similar to my code. I just want to have that 'stable' known version just in case to make my life easier if worse comes to worse again. I'm by no means a Linux guru so configuring settings that might normally take 15 minutes for some takes me an hour or 2.

Comment: @drewbenn that custom boot option..... if you download something like MySQL would it retain tables and users created as well or just the MySQL application itself?